# Calling a setTimeOut after another setTimeOut in Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two `setTimeOut` here. The second `setTimeOut` must be called after the first time out.

```
 setTimeout(() => { 
        mack.classList.add('loaded'); 
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(() => { 
        location.reload(true);
    }, 4000);
```

But I know that this is not a good solution on this. So I tried to do a Promise:

```
  const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

     Promise.all([
          timer(3000).then(mack.classList.add('loaded')),
          timer(1000).then(location.reload(true))
    ])
```

This however, did not work. How can I fix this to make it call in order? Also, is there a version to do this using asynchronous?

Comment: Put the second timer inside the `then` of the first timer? Also, pass a function to the `then` like you do with `setTimeout`. At the moment it won't work

Comment: Do you want to run second after first?

Comment: For `await timer(3000)
await timer(1000)` how to I add the code then like the adding of classlist?

Comment: I removed my comment, as it turned out, i had to cut too much, to make it fit. However, you'd use something like `(async () => { await timer(3000); mack.classList.add('loaded'); await timer(1000); location.reload(true); })();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the promises, and then passing them to `Promise.all`, which waits for all of them simultaneously.

You want to start the second timer in response to the first timer.

This would do you you want:

```
timer(3000)
  .then(() => {
       mack.classList.add('loaded');
       return timer(1000);
  }).then(() => location.reload(true));
```

If you wanted this in an an async function:

```
async function example() {
   await timer(3000);
   mack.classList.add('loaded');
   await timer(1000);
   location.reload(true);
}

example().then(() => console.log('async function complete!'));
```

Comment: Do I need to put this all inside the `Promise.all` to run?

Comment: @AichiGarcia No, you do not need `Promise.all`. `Promise.all` is for when you are running different pieces of asynchronous code simultaneously, while in this example you want to run the code in sequence.

Comment: SOrry to ask this again, but is there a way to have the same version in asychronous js?

Comment: @AichiGarcia What do you mean by 'asynchronous js'?

Comment: I mean async function the same version?

Comment: @AichiGarcia I have added an `async` example. If location.reload is failing to do what you want then that would be a different question.

Answer (score 3):

You are nearly there,

To use timer the way you want, you can use `async / await`, just remember to be able to use `await`, it has to be called withing another `async` function, here I've just placed inside an IFFE to achieve this..

```js
const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

(async function () {
  console.log('Waiting 3 seconds');
  await timer(3000);
  console.log('loaded');
  await timer(1000);
  console.log('reload');
}());
```

Comment: How to run the `mack.classList.add('loaded');` inside the `await`?

Comment: @JonesSmith  In the above snippet, the bit were I put `console.log('loaded')` replace with the classList bit,  I've not put that part of the code in the snippet, so that it's a working snippet and the OP can click `Run code snippet` to see it working.